# Timezone Conversion In SQL Query

Tags: mysql, parsing, time, timezone

I am trying to write a SQL query that checks a requested 'deadline' against the table's 'deadline' field and I would like to do this in 24 hour EST time but many of the values of the table's 'deadline' field vary. 
Here's an example:

```
Row - Deadline
1   - 05:00 EST
2   - 05:00 ET
3   - 03:00 CT
4   - 2:00pm CT/3:00pm ET
```

Is it possible to parse the 'deadline' field while selecting and do any maths necessary (if, for example the value is 03:00 CT read as 04:00 for EST)

Thanks in advance

Comment: the 'deadline' field, by the way, is just a varchar and not a timestamp obv

Comment: That's not even in 1NF... `2:00pm CT/3:00pm ET`

Comment: @djacobson - It is MySQL

Comment: @MostyMostacho - Believe me, this is just one of many things stressing me out about this DB

Comment: Given the highly-variable nature of the data, there's no simple way to do what you're asking, and SQL is certainly a poor fit for it. You need logic that can parse time values with their associated time zones out of arbitrary strings, correctly interpret the time zone from a non-standard abbreviation, and then convert the time to a different time zone. That's far too broad a problem to be readily answerable here.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a stored procedure